# Check if map in C++ contains all the keys from another map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, set, intersection

I am planning to use two maps in C++, of type: `std::map<char, Node>`, where `Node` is a custom class. Suppose I have two maps, `m1` and `m2` of the type above, I want to find out whether `m1` contains *all* keys present in `m2`. In other words, I want to verify that the intersection of the set of keys of `m1` and `m2` is the same as the set of keys of `m2`.

I could iterate over all keys in `m2` and do a `find()` or `count()` on `m1`, but that would seem like a waste and would probably be slow. I say this because the keys are stored as a binary search tree in sorted order in an `std::map`, and so each of find/count will take O(logn), and for the next key in `m2`, the same path in the keys of `m1` will have to be traversed from the beginning.

I am new to STL, so please forgive my ignorance on what seems like something that should be doable easily. Also, some simple example code snippets or links to code snippets will be very helpful to understand better. I cannot use non-standard libraries, including boost.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the keys of a `map` are sorted, you can iterate through both of them at the same time and compare the keys to each other. If `key(m1) < key(m2)`, increment the iterator for m1; if `key(m2) < key(m1)` then m2 contains a key not in m1.

This is O(n).

Comment: This is nice - similar to merge algorithm for sorting lists. Thanks!

Comment: This is Θ(m2 + m1) while the original algorithm was Θ(m2 * log(m1)) (naming sizes after their map). Whether this is better actually depends on the size of `m1` relative to that of `m2`...