# Is there any way I can make this coordinate comparisson function more efficient?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The following function takes three word objects and checks each word's letter coordinates (in a table) against each other. The idea is to get combinations of three words from a list that don't have intersecting letter coordinates. However when you have over 600000 possible combinations this becomes very time consuming.

```
bool lettersIntersect(word one, word two, word three)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < one.getLength(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < two.getLength(); j++)
            if(one.getLetterPosition(i).x == two.getLetterPosition(j).x && one.getLetterPosition(i).y == two.getLetterPosition(j).y)
                return true;
    for(int i = 0; i < two.getLength(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < three.getLength(); j++)
            if(two.getLetterPosition(i).x == three.getLetterPosition(j).x && two.getLetterPosition(i).y == three.getLetterPosition(j).y)
                return true;
    for(int i = 0; i < three.getLength(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < one.getLength(); j++)
            if(three.getLetterPosition(i).x == one.getLetterPosition(j).x && three.getLetterPosition(i).y == one.getLetterPosition(j).y)
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Judging by what it looks like they are as parameters (containers) start with a basic fundamental: Pass them by const-reference. That aside, knowing the definitions of this class (`word`) would probably go a long way in answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just give you 1 hint which striked me instantly. Don't blame me if its misleading. You can just try once at your end and see the performance.

Create map (use stl) for each word objects i.e. `map_one`, `map_two`, and `map_three`

Add co-ordinate value as key for each letter of a given word object to its respective map.

Then check using these maps whether there is an intersection. 
[Check if map in C++ contains all the keys from another map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775028/check-if-map-in-c-contains-all-the-keys-from-another-map)

Comment: Ah and this seemed like such a good idea at first, but I think maps would work better for much larger tables. For my small table this approach increased execution time to two times the original. However, your idea gave me an even better one. Using a vector and only 3 for statements I managed to reduce the execution time THREE times! Now by splitting the process into threads I should get it to well under a second. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see possible to optimize is avoiding double checks:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < one.getLength(); i++)
        for(int j = i+1; j < two.getLength(); j++)
            if(one.getLetterPosition(i).x == two.getLetterPosition(j).x && one.getLetterPosition(i).y == two.getLetterPosition(j).y)
            return true;
```

The second for loop was changed from j = 0, to j = i+1, which makes you do the checks in half the time.

Checking between two coordinates points is a n^2 (n-square) problem, which means that the time required to do the checks is proportional to square the number of elements you can check. I thikn there's no other way to optimize this other than avoiding double checks, like I explained.

Of course, in addition to passing by references, like was suggested to you already.

Answer (score 0):

On this homework problem or other learning exercise, you are intended to use a method you have been taught previously that rearranges data to make searching faster. Having rearranged the data, you should be able to find a way to scan it efficiently to find duplicates.